# Biblion, Django blog error

Tags: python, django, blogs

I am trying to install biblion, a blog built on django on my local computer, and then upload it (but that will be a different post I'm sure).  I've installed the required.txt but everytime I try to sync the db, or run the server, it gives me this error: "Error: One or more models did not validate:
biblion.image: "image_path": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ ."

Any idea what's going on?  This seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Can't really see how that message could be any more helpful. It tells you that you need PIL, and how to install it. What else do you need?

Answer (score 3):

> To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging Library.
> Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

You need to install PIL.

- Windows: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/
- Mac: install [brew](https://brew.sh/), then `brew install pil`
- Linux: use the package manager and search for `python-imaging`